# AWS: "Custom Domain" is stuck in the "Updating" state for a whole day

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I had set up a custom domain for API Gateway. I have tried to update its BasePath and SecurityPolicy using sam and now it is stuck in the "Updating" state on the UI. Trying to delete it from AWS CLI also causes the following error.

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the DeleteDomainName operation: 
There is already an update in progress for the domain reminders.thestarware.com. 
Please wait until the current update finishes before making another request.
```

Even deleting the whole API Gateway does not resolve it. Do you have any idea about how I can force delete it?

Comment: Did you try deleting it from the cloud formation console?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, when you utilize a custom domain in API Gateway, API Gateway saves the custom domain independently of your APIs so that you can delete an API without deleting your domain, or so that you can change the API that the domain points to if you need to.

Have you tried deleting your custom domain from API Gateway via the AWS Management Console / web browser interface?

1. Log in to the AWS console
2. Navigate to the API Gateway management page for your region. An example URL for the us-west-2 region is:
   https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway
3. Click on "Custom domain names" as shown in the image below. Then you should be able to click on your domain and try to delete it using the "Delete" button shown in the image below. API Gateway Custom domain names management page

[image]